# TZ database and multiple US timezones

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I am using pytz to associate time zones with my user profiles. Originally I thought it would just include time zones such as PST, CST, EST, but when I run `pytz.country_timezones('US')` I receive the following list:
`[u'America/New_York', u'America/Detroit', u'America/Kentucky/Louisville', u'America/Kentucky/Monticello', u'America/Indiana/Indianapolis', u'America/Indiana/Vincennes', u'America/Indiana/Winamac', u'America/Indiana/Marengo', u'America/Indiana/Petersburg', u'America/Indiana/Vevay', u'America/Chicago', u'America/Indiana/Tell_City', u'America/Indiana/Knox', u'America/Menominee', u'America/North_Dakota/Center', u'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem', u'America/North_Dakota/Beulah', u'America/Denver', u'America/Boise', u'America/Phoenix', u'America/Los_Angeles', u'America/Metlakatla', u'America/Anchorage', u'America/Juneau', u'America/Sitka', u'America/Yakutat', u'America/Nome', u'America/Adak', u'Pacific/Honolulu']`

In addition:
`pytz.all_timezones` == 582
`pytz.common_timezones` == 432

I live in Texas and always select Chicago because that's just how the internet works, but now that I have to think into this, I'm really confused as to which time zones we should be using in our application and which are redundant. For example, [America/Kentucky/Louisville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Kentucky/Louisville) is the same as [America/Kentucky/Monticello](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Kentucky/Monticello) - why do they both exist? I know that it has to do with Indiana's historical time zone fiasco but why hasn't the database been updated to remove redundancy?

I've never lived in Indiana so I have no idea what time zones residents are accustomed to seeing. Also because of anomalies like Arizona who don't partake in DST, it's not as simple as just including PST, CST, etc.

**Is there some formal subset of TZ database time zones to account for all US residents?**

Comment: Backwards. PST, CST, etc only work for Arizona and other places that don't partake in DST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For example, America/Kentucky/Louisville is the same as America/Kentucky/Monticello - why do they both exist?

Because they're *not* the same. They may observe the same rules from now onwards, but they haven't *always* done so. Having separate zone IDs for them means that given an instant in time in the past, you can still determine what the local time was at that point.

In the case of Louisville and Monticello, looking at the data it looks like they differed as recently as the 1990s. Here's the data from the 1990s, in terms of which periods the zones observed which names and offsets:

```
America/Kentucky/Louisville
EST: [1989-10-29T06:00:00Z, 1990-04-01T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1990-04-01T07:00:00Z, 1990-10-28T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1990-10-28T06:00:00Z, 1991-04-07T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1991-04-07T07:00:00Z, 1991-10-27T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1991-10-27T06:00:00Z, 1992-04-05T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1992-04-05T07:00:00Z, 1992-10-25T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1992-10-25T06:00:00Z, 1993-04-04T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1993-04-04T07:00:00Z, 1993-10-31T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1993-10-31T06:00:00Z, 1994-04-03T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1994-04-03T07:00:00Z, 1994-10-30T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1994-10-30T06:00:00Z, 1995-04-02T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1995-04-02T07:00:00Z, 1995-10-29T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1995-10-29T06:00:00Z, 1996-04-07T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1996-04-07T07:00:00Z, 1996-10-27T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1996-10-27T06:00:00Z, 1997-04-06T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1997-04-06T07:00:00Z, 1997-10-26T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1997-10-26T06:00:00Z, 1998-04-05T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1998-04-05T07:00:00Z, 1998-10-25T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1998-10-25T06:00:00Z, 1999-04-04T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)
EDT: [1999-04-04T07:00:00Z, 1999-10-31T06:00:00Z) -04 (+01)
EST: [1999-10-31T06:00:00Z, 2000-04-02T07:00:00Z) -05 (+00)

America/Kentucky/Monticello
CST: [1989-10-29T07:00:00Z, 1990-04-01T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1990-04-01T08:00:00Z, 1990-10-28T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1990-10-28T07:00:00Z, 1991-04-07T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1991-04-07T08:00:00Z, 1991-10-27T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1991-10-27T07:00:00Z, 1992-04-05T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1992-04-05T08:00:00Z, 1992-10-25T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1992-10-25T07:00:00Z, 1993-04-04T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1993-04-04T08:00:00Z, 1993-10-31T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1993-10-31T07:00:00Z, 1994-04-03T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1994-04-03T08:00:00Z, 1994-10-30T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1994-10-30T07:00:00Z, 1995-04-02T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1995-04-02T08:00:00Z, 1995-10-29T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1995-10-29T07:00:00Z, 1996-04-07T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1996-04-07T08:00:00Z, 1996-10-27T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1996-10-27T07:00:00Z, 1997-04-06T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1997-04-06T08:00:00Z, 1997-10-26T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1997-10-26T07:00:00Z, 1998-04-05T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1998-04-05T08:00:00Z, 1998-10-25T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1998-10-25T07:00:00Z, 1999-04-04T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
CDT: [1999-04-04T08:00:00Z, 1999-10-31T07:00:00Z) -05 (+01)
CST: [1999-10-31T07:00:00Z, 2000-04-02T08:00:00Z) -06 (+00)
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. So when it comes to listing these on the front end, how does one go about choosing a subset that includes all current US timezones but excludes historical redundancies?

Comment: @praterade: Well, you'd need to work out how far back you want to go, for a start. Then you'd need some way of determining whether zones are equal based on that time range. [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) lets you do this pretty easily, but I don't know about other libraries, I'm afraid. I can give you the relevant Noda Time code if you'd be able to use that somewhere in the backend to regularly populate a file (for example).

Comment: Appreciated but I'm good for now. I'm just disappointed to learn there's not an official normalized list. Seems like TZ database would at least be able to include FK's to an 'official' time zone for that region (as in Monticello maps to New York, which could be the regulated time zone for EST)

Comment: @praterade: How would such a normalized list work, when everyone's requirements could be different, in terms of when they'd want to consider zones "equal". You might want to look at the zone1970.tab file in recent TZDB releases though.

Comment: I mean it would be great to have a current list (date >= today) of US timezones that did not contain duplicates.

Comment: @prateradeq: Right, to *start* with that's a very US-centric view... and why "today"? Why not "5 years ago"? Just because your application might need it from today doesn't mean that's the only or even the most common requirement.

Comment: Sure, makes sense. So if it's a requirement to associate users with a time zone, my options are to either include the whole list above or add individual zones as they become necessary?

Comment: @praterade: Or have your own automated process to filter. I suspect it's not too hard in any half-decent API... it's just that Noda Time is the only one I can do it for off by heart :)

Answer (score 1):

> For example, America/Kentucky/Louisville is the same as America/Kentucky/Monticello - why do they both exist?

The current time at both locations may be the same, but that hasn't always been the case.

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -E'
   my @tz = qw( America/Kentucky/Monticello America/Kentucky/Louisville );

   my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
      pattern   => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
      time_zone => "UTC",
      on_error  => "croak",
   );

   my $dt = $format->parse_datetime("2000-05-01T00:00:00");

   for my $tz (@tz) {
      say $dt->clone->set_time_zone($tz)->iso8601;
   }
'
2000-04-30T19:00:00
2000-04-30T20:00:00
```

It can't be removed from the database, because that would break programs that deal with dates that occurred in the past.